# Grub won't detect Windows 10 on NVME SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10 a month or 2 ago, but had issues installing and after it installed Grub would never show up at all and I had to choose whether to boot Windows or Ubuntu by changing boot order in UEFI settings. Eventually (today) I was able to get Grub to finally show up (apparently for some absolutely stupid reason a setting got set in /etc/default/grub called GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden which prevents Grub from showing during timeout period unless you hit escape), but it still won't detect Windows 10 and allow me to boot to it. My current drive setup is I have a 128GB SATA SSD that Ubuntu is installed on, a 1TB SATA SSD that I have my Ubuntu Home directory on, a 500GB NVME SSD that Windows 10 is installed on, and a 1TB HDD that I use for bulk storage on my Windows system.
Here is the output when I run `sudo update-grub`:

```
ubuntu:~$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-43-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-42-generic
error: invalid volume.
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdc1.  Check your device.map.
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The partition sdc1 (I suppose is the boot partition of windows) which kind of partition is?

Comment: sdc1 is my 1TB HDD for windows, it does not contain the boot partition. Here are the results of both from fdisk -l https://pastebin.com/E25dZwWf

Comment: The boot partition of windows is stored some were else or is not present at all? If is the second case (not present) that is the reason why grub cannot find it

Comment: Shouldn't the boot partition of windows be nvme0n1p1 in that fdisk results? It is marked as boot at least

Comment: Ok, I get it, what about you mount that partition and run "sudo os-prober"? It find also windows partito on as well?

Comment: os-prober doesn't return anything. https://pastebin.com/9HxYDPd2
Should I mount the boot partition to a specific location or just anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, it seems I expected too much from Microsoft. Even though I installed Windows within the last year and just expected it installed as UEFI, it was installed as BIOS and Ubuntu was installed as UEFI. Just converted Windows to UEFI and it seems to work fine.

Comment: lol, that is nothing about expectation, anyway, sure both system use UEFI, bot of the disks had dos partition table and as far as I remember UEFI require GPT partition table, anyway important is you resolve, about your answer i think is much better to say your troubleshoot steps and action taken to fix the issues, like this others folling in same situation can find this question useful

Comment: Yeah, like @AtomiX84 says, what is the steps you took to fix this?